# Faster unique() to compare keys in two data frames

Tags: r

I have the following problem when trying to make the following analysis with big data:

I have two data frames A and B with the same primary key (over multiple columns), but data frame A has in addition a date variable with it.

I now want to check if for all unique entities in data frame A if I have an entry in dataframe B as well. I do this with the following function:

```
checkMissing <- function(A, B, primary_key) {
  A <- unique(A[,primary_key])
  B <- unique(B[,primary_key])
  return(A[!A %in% B,])
}
```

As it turns out, the unique part is terrible slow when A is getting more and more data (I checked for something like 15MN rows and it took about 30 seconds on my machine).

Is there a smarter way to check if entities are missing in B without using dplyr? (base R would be perfect, but data.table works as well)

Here a reproduceable example:

```
library(tictoc)
checkMissing <- function(A, B, primary_key) {
  tic("making data unique")
  A <- unique(A[,primary_key])
  B <- unique(B[,primary_key])
  toc()
  return(A[!A %in% B,])
}
# creating the dummy key data

ID1 <- 250000
ID2 <- seq(1,ID1/100,1)
ID3 <- seq(1,ID1/10000,1)

tmp <- data.frame("ID1" = seq(1,ID1,1),
                  "ID2" = sample(ID2, ID1, replace = TRUE),
                  "ID3" = sample(ID3, ID1, replace = TRUE)
)

#creating the date sequence
dates <- data.frame("date" = seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2019-02-28"),1))

#cross join to get data frame A
df.A <- merge(dates,tmp,by=NULL)

# create data frame B
df.B <- unique(df.A[,c("ID1","ID2","ID3")])

tic("overall time")
df.result <- checkMissing(df.A,df.B,c("ID1","ID2","ID3"))
toc()
```

Thanks!
Stephan

Comment: You're looking for an anti-join I think? My data.table skills are a little rusty, but maybe this: `setDT(df.A)[!df.B, on = c("ID1","ID2","ID3")]`? I may have the two data frames backwards, I'm not sure. (There's a dplyr anti_join function too, in case other people are interested.)

Comment: Hi @joran, you are right - this is _way_ faster than my original approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as joran pointed out in his comment - the anti join implementation in data.table is way faster:

```
setDT(df.A)[!df.B, on = c("ID1","ID2","ID3")]
```

On my test data execution reduced from something between 30-35 seconds to less then 2 seconds.

Although still interested in a faster base R version this is a correct answer.

Best
Stephan